# Javascript get subsring between two of the same characters?

Tags: javascript, string, substring

I'm trying to extract a substring from another string that exists between two of the same characters.

This is my entire string:

> abcdefg?hijk?lmnop

And this is the substring that I want to extract:

> abcdefg?**hijk**?lmnop

_

I tried using this code:

```
currenturl.substring(currenturl.lastIndexOf("?") + 1, currenturl.lastIndexOf("?"));
```

But it only returns "?"

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `indexOf` which returns the index of the first matching `?` as the first param to `subString` :

```js
const currenturl = "abcdefg?hijk?lmnop";
const result = currenturl.substring(currenturl.indexOf("?") + 1, currenturl.lastIndexOf("?"));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked great